# Log message printed for promises during a `push` to an array but not a call to `Promise.all`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand something about the following behavior for promises.

When I `push` a promise to the `promises` array, the `console.log` is executed. I think this is because as I `push`, I actually execute the promises.

But then when I try doing `Promise.all`, I don't see the same `console.log` messages being printed, it's just silence. I can see the return values of each `resolve` if I destructure them from the `Promise.all` and `console.log` them, but, again, I don't see the `console.log` messages (such as `Printed for promise A during push`).

Why is this happening?

```
import * as React from "react";

const promiseA = async ({}) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Printed for promise A during push");

    resolve("promise a resolved");
  });
};

const promiseB = async ({}) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Printed for promise B during push");

    resolve("promise b resolved");
  });
};

const Component = React.memo(() => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    init();
  }, []);

  const init = React.useCallback(async () => {
    let promises = [];
    promises.push(promiseA({})); // 'Printed for promise A during push'
    promises.push(promiseB({})); // 'Printed for promise B during push'

    await Promise.all(promises); // silence, nothing is printed

    /*
        // And if I do the following, I see the strings in `resolve`:
        const [responseA, responseB] = await Promise.all(promises);
    
        console.log("responseA", responseA); // responseA promise a resolved
        console.log("responseB", responseB); // responseB promise a resolved
    */
  }, []);

  return <div />;
});

export default Component;
```

Comment: Did you expect to see the messages get printed _more_ than once? You only call the functions once each.

Comment: Isn't the `Promise.all` supposed to await both promises? In each promise, there's a `console.log`. So yes, I was under the impression that I'd see those `console.log`s being printed twice -- once when I push to `promises` and once when I `await Promise.all`

Comment: Yes, and it does, hence you get the resolved values. You only _create_ the promises once, when you push them to the array, it's not at all clear why you expected them to run twice each.

Comment: Are you saying that when I do `promises.push(promiseA({}));`, I'm not actually calling the `resolve` method of `promiseA`?

Comment: What do you mean _"actually calling"_? You're calling a function which creates a promise and passes a callback function (the "executor"), and when the callback is invoked with the resolve (and ignored reject) parameter by the runtime, _that_ logs then calls resolve. Fundamentally you're pointlessly wrapping synchronous code in a promise (you could `Promise.resolve(whatever)`, or just not), and the resolve call is immediately after one where you clearly see exactly when it runs.

Comment: there's nothing asynchronous, so as soon as you create the promises, they are  resolved.  `Promises.all()` just creates a new promise that resolves when all the promises are resolved, which they already are. But it doesn't reset or run the code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises can't be "executed". Promises don't describe *actions*, they describe the *results of some actions*.

The function you pass to the `Promise` constructor is called immediately when the constructor is called. Its job is to *initiate* the actions, the result of which the promise represents. That means that the actions are initiated when the promise is created.

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log("Printed during promise creation");

  resolve("resolved");
});
```

...is the same as writing...

```
console.log("Printed at the same time, but from outside the Promise callback");

new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve("resolved");
});
```

So in your code, it's not `push` *creating* those promises. It's you calling those promise-creating functions.

```
promises.push( promiseA({}) );
//                     ^^^^--- calling function `promiseA`
```

The thing that you made your functions `async` can be another source of confusion. Let's rewrite your code in a bit clearer way:

```
//This used to be named `promiseA`
const createPromiseA = () => {
  console.log("Called createPromiseA, about to create promiseA")
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Promise A created");

    resolve("Promise A resolved");
  });
};

//This used to be named `promiseB`
const createPromiseB = () => {
  console.log("Called createPromiseB, about to create promiseB")
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Promise B created");

    resolve("Promise B resolved");
  });
};

let promises = [];

let promiseA = createPromiseA(); //Called createPromiseA, about to create promiseA | Created promiseA
let promiseB = createPromiseB(); //Called createPromiseB, about to create promiseB | Created promiseB

//All the following will just move those promises around, no logs.
promises.push(promiseA);
promises.push(promiseB);

//Neither will this log
let results = await Promise.all(promises); 

//Logs the results as expected
console.log(results) //["Promise A resolved", "Promise B resolved"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the confusion here is your naming.

`promiseA` and `promiseB` aren't promises in your code, they are functions that  returns a `Promise`.

You call the functions `promiseA` and `promiseB`, and you add the return values to the array.

Using the return value of a function will not call the function again.
The promise objects returned can be used to wait for the code in the functions to complete. In this case, they aren't asynchronous so they will be immediately resolved/complete.

`Promise.all` returns a new promise that is resolved when all the promises in the array are resolved. In this case, that is again immediately.

But, don't confuse the function called `promise` with the return value which is actually a `Promise`